# php merge child arrays with a common key

Tags: php, arrays

I return an array of elements from a MySql table, and the array looks like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'BMW',
      'amount' => '5',
    ),
  1 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Ford',
      'amount' => '2',
    ),
  2 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'BMW',
      'amount' => '4',
    ),
  3 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Ford',
      'amount' => '8',
    ),
  4 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Fiat',
      'amount' => '2',
    ),
)
```

I like to merge together all arrays with the same 'name' element and add together the corresponding 'amount' elements so that the output of the above array will be:

```
array (
  0 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'BMW',
      'amount' => '9',
    ),
  1 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Ford',
      'amount' => '10',
    ),
  2 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Fiat',
      'amount' => '2',
    ),
)
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried to find an array function that can do the work.

Comment: It would be a better idea to fix your query to return what you want rather than fiddle with a less than useful set of results

Comment: So show us the query

Comment: Id probably do something like `SELECT name, amount FROM mytable GROUP BY name`.

Comment: Thanks RiggFolly & Xorifelse., SELECT name, SUM(amount) as amount FROM mytable GROUP BY name

Comment: Might wanna aggregate `amount` with `SUM()`, like `SELECT name, SUM(amount) sum FROM ...` .

Comment: @Xorifelse Make that an answer. It'll get my UV

Comment: Maybe https://gist.github.com/mcaskill/baaee44487653e1afc0d will work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manipulating data with PHP you can select the requested data directly with MySQL using the `GROUP BY` statement.

```
SELECT name, SUM(amount) total FROM mytable GROUP BY name
```

`SUM()` in this case is the [aggregate function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp), others are available as well.

While looping you should be able to access the data like so:

```
echo $row['name'], $row['total'];
```

Comment: Doing this you should get the array you want out of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try 
array_merge_recursive();

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

and then to loop result array and sum elements.

or you use this code or I think solutions below are also very reasonable

```
$result = array();
foreach ($tab as $key => $elem){
        if (array_key_exists($elem['name'],$result)) {
            $result[$elem['name']] += $elem['amount'];
        } else {
            $result[$elem['name']] = $elem['amount'];
        }
}
```

Comment: FIx the problem, not the symptom. Make the SQL do all the work thats what it is for